# using R to download xlsx working book from Google Sheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an R script that works to download the xlsx file from google sheets, but when I change the link to the new published spreadsheet link, the file output has the error "file format or file extension is not valid" and every time I run the code the file size is different.  The only thing I changed was the sheet id?

This works

```
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
require(RCurl)
url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ghgo1OYeFlPYoxHCewTJbYMo5LLJ4DxU-IAGP1BxeVU/export?format=xlsx"
destfile = "C:\\Users\\atrombley\\Desktop\\Work\\Prosper.xlsx"
x = getBinaryURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
writeBin(x, destfile, useBytes = TRUE)
```

The code that doesn't work?? Any help is appreciated!

```
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
require(RCurl)
url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15cQsscKj9aR5anVgUQmr9KsBQbfZ8E7gigF1ikwr42E/export?format=xlsx"
destfile = "C:\\Users\\atrombley\\Desktop\\Work\\Prosperv.xlsx"
x = getBinaryURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
writeBin(x, destfile, useBytes = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you make sure the file is indeed an excel file? This could be some other extension file, which has been changed to .xlsx format. You could also have a try with changing the file of .xlsx to .xls to see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure the second file is accessible to you? When I go to each of those URLs directly in my browser, I can open the first Excel file, but I get a "request access" message for the second one. What you're downloading might actually just be an html file of the "request access" page. That's the result I got when I ran your code on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, if i copy and paste the URL it downloads the xlsx file to my local

Comment: If you change the output file name to `Prospserv.html`, do you still get an error or does the file get saved to your hard drive? I'm wondering if `R` is not able to access the file and is downloading an html gatekeeper page instead.

Comment: I am not getting an error from R even when it is an xlsx - I only get the error upon trying to open the file that it has downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Try the new `googlesheets` package, which is an R API for Google Sheets:

https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

This snippet will install the package, and download public Sheet to a local xlsx file:

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
gap_key <- "1HT5B8SgkKqHdqHJmn5xiuaC04Ngb7dG9Tv94004vezA"
download_ss(gap_key, to = "gapminder.xlsx")
```

Assuming you have Sheets already in your Google Drive, you can download them in other ways, such as by Sheet title.